# How to connect two components in a same component created on click of add button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating multiple counters on click and I want to connect the two counters, When I increase the value in the first counter it should automatically decrease in the second counter. Can you suggest any solution where I can communicate with multiple counters as I can generate multiple counters on click?

```js
const Counter = ({ value, onIncrement, onDecrement, hideIncrement }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <span>{value}</span>
          {value > 0 && (
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                onDecrement();
              }}
            >
              -
            </button>
          )}
          {hideIncrement === false && value < 10 && (
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                onIncrement();
              }}
            >
              +
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    const Counters = () => {
      const [counters, setCounters] = React.useState([4, 0, 0, 5]);
    
      const sum = counters.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, 0);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <p>Sum: {sum}</p>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setCounters([...counters, 0]);
            }}
          >
            Add counter
          </button>
          <br />
          <div>
            {counters.map((value, index) => (
              <Counter
                value={value}
                hideIncrement={sum >= 20}
                onIncrement={() => {
                  const countersCopy = [...counters];
                  countersCopy[index] += 1;
                  setCounters(countersCopy);
                }}
                onDecrement={() => {
                  const countersCopy = [...counters];
                  countersCopy[index] -= 1;
                  setCounters(countersCopy);
                }}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render(<Counters />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your edit, Can you suggest any solution for my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass state to Couter component:
try this:

```
const Counter = ({value, onIncrement, onDecrement, hideIncrement, 
addStatus, counterIndex, index}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        if (counterIndex === index - 1) onDecrement(addStatus);
    }, [counterIndex, addStatus])
    return (
        <div>
            <span>{value}</span>
            {value > 0 && (
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        onDecrement();
                    }}
                >
                    -
                </button>
            )}
            {hideIncrement === false && value < 10 && (
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        onIncrement();
                    }}
                >
                    +
                </button>
            )}
        </div>
    );
};

const Counters = () => {
    const [counters, setCounters] = React.useState([4, 4, 4, 5]);
    const [addStatus, setAddStatus] = useState(0);
    const [counterIndex, setCounterIndex] = useState(0);
    const sum = counters.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item, 0);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Sum: {sum}</p>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    setCounters([...counters, 0]);
                }}
            >
                Add counter
            </button>
            <br/>
            <div>
                {counters.map((value, index) => (
                    <Counter
                        value={value}
                        index={index}
                        addStatus={addStatus}
                        counterIndex={counterIndex}
                        hideIncrement={sum >= 20}
                        onIncrement={() => {
                            const countersCopy = [...counters];
                            countersCopy[index] += 1;
                            setAddStatus(a => a + 1)
                            setCounterIndex(index)
                            setCounters(countersCopy);
                        }}
                        onDecrement={() => {
                            const countersCopy = [...counters];
                            countersCopy[index] -= 1;
                            setCounters(countersCopy);
                        }}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will try and let you know the result.

Comment: Hi Reza, In the solution, you suggested the second counter is only decrementing based on the first counter even if it increments or decrements. What i am trying to do is i want to connect both counters where if i decrease in counter 1 it should increase in counter 2, And if i decrease in counter 2 it should increase in counter 1. This means both should be in synchronize eighter 1 counter increase the other should decrease and vice-versa. Can you please suggest to me a solution for this? Thank you

Comment: you can add another state to onDecrement like onIncrement and pass it to counter for example setMinusStatus()  to onDecrement