# How to count values in another component's state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Suppose that I have two components A and B and within component B I want to count the number of items in one of the states of component A based on some criteria set in component B.

In practice what I have is a table of values and when I click the a button I want to count all the values that have today's date but when I try to implement this the state containing that data is never initialized even though the table component has rendered correctly.

That that I am using hooks.

Comment: This comes up a lot in react!  I have answers to two similar questions, [How to set one component's state from another component in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62365670/2430549)  And also: [Correct way to share functions between components in React](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51661103/2430549)  Cheers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70417496/how-to-connect-two-components-in-a-same-component-created-on-click-of-add-button/70417750#70417750

Comment: I don't think either of these addressed my question but thank you for the help.